# Trying to use new package

Tags: java, package, importerror, worldwind

Basically I've downloaded a package for the WorldWind JDK that allows for rendering of 3ds models.   However, for the life of me, I've been unable to use any of these files using standard imports, and my googlefoo is failing pretty hard in coming up with a way to use them.

import on the primary renderer file is something like this

```
import gov.nasa.worldwind.Movable;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Angle;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.LatLon;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Quaternion;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Vec4;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.globes.Globe;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.DrawContext;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Renderable;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.util.Logging;
import javax.media.opengl.GL;

//Problems reside with these imports
import net.java.joglutils.model.ModelFactory;
import net.java.joglutils.model.examples.DisplayListRenderer;
import net.java.joglutils.model.geometry.Model;

public class Movable3DModel implements Renderable, Movable{
}
```

The error when trying to use them is

> the import net cannot be resolved.

The files come in a string of different folders, so I need all of them to be used, and am completely lost as to where to go from here ><

EDIT1:
Throwing in some edits to answer questions about my question
This is using Eclipse.   The WorldWind dependancies are using a few JOGLs that you import, those are not the issue.   The issue is trying to use

Comment: What IDE are you using (if any)? Eclipse?

Comment: Your description is somewhat confusing. Your sample code seems to indicate that you're experiencing problems with `net.java.jogutils.` packages and not `worldwind`. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: You should show us exactly what one of these errors says or else we won't be able to exactly help you.

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE

I fixed the error that I am getting for (hopefully) some clarity.  The WorldWind imports are not the issue, but the net.java.joglutils.modle     I am not sure what to do with these because there is no jogl file that is available for the eclipse import.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classpath issue.  I downloaded worldwind myself and see it comes in a zip.  You can't point your classpath to that.  You have to extract it and add the jars in there to your classpath.  I see a "worldwind.jar" in there.  It seems to have the classes you're importing.

Adding it to your classpath really depends on your environment that you're using.  You should take a step back and learn more about the classpath first.  There are plenty of good tutorials.  Here's some:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html If you're on solaris/linux-like environment
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html If you're on windows

The classpath is essential to learning how to debug java programs.  If you learn to understand it now, you'll be a better java programmer forever